# General Linear group on $\mathbb{Z}_p$

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory

I have to prove that if $p$ is a prime and $A \in GL_n(\mathbb{Z}_p)$ is such that $A^{{p}^k}=1$ for some $k$, then there exist $v \neq 0$ such that $Av=v$.

Can someone give me a hint about how to approach this problem? I am studying for my qualyfing exam, so, please don't give me a entire answer, just give a hint or some hints to give the first steps...

Since now I thank you all for the attention.

Comment: You want to show that $1$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, that is $\det(I-A)=0$. But $(I-A)^{p^k}=0$...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Consider the sizes of the orbits of $\langle A\rangle$ acting on $\mathbb{F}_p^n$.

Comment: Ok I am gonna try it now! I was trying to consider the orbits of the entire GLn acting the powers of the field. Thank you so much!

Comment: Very good hint imo: set of fixed points by a $\;p\,-$ group on some set. +1

Comment: Indeed, there are $p^n$ points. All orbits have a size a divisor of $p$. The orbit of the zero vector has size $1$, the other orbits can't all have size $p$ thus there must be at least one other  orbit of size $1$, and it  does not contain the zero vector.

Comment: @BogaertsMarc You mean all orbits have size a divisor of $p^k$, and the other orbits can't all have size a multiple of $p$.

Comment: why the orbits cannot have size dividing $p^k$? Is it because $k<p$ and the number of orbits is $p^n$? Then is all of them has a size dividing $p^k$ the it is some $p^m$ for some $m$ and then the size of $\langle A \rangle$ is gonna be $\sum |Orb(v)| > 1 + p^n >|\langle A \rangle|$ and it is a contradiction?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake,  I meant that the size of the orbits is a multiple of $p$ or $1$ (orbit stabilizer theorem). The total number of points is a multiple of $p$, but one of the orbits (that of the zero vector) has size one, thus there must be other orbits with size $1$.

Comment: @bttmbrcelo I never said the orbits cannot have size dividing $p^k$. In fact, they all *do* have size dividing $p^k$. That's the orbit-stabilizer theorem, applied to the group $\langle A\rangle$ acting. The question is if $\{0\}$ can be the only orbit of size $1$. The argument is the same as in the proof of the third Sylow theorem. It uses modular arithmetic, not inequalities.

Comment: @arctictern This is indeed the case

Comment: @arctictern sorry! I wrote dividing but I would like to write multiple.